# Are monads just ways of composing functions which would otherwise not compose?

Tags: haskell, monads

The bind function seems remarkably similar like a composition function. And it helps in composing functions which return monads.

Is there anything more enlightening about monads than this idea?

Comment: Even more like function composition than bind is `(<=<) :: Monad m => (b -> m c) -> (a -> m b) -> a -> m c`.

Comment: And the "Monad laws" basically boil down to associativity of `<=<` with `return` as the identity element of that operation.

Answer (score 15):

> Is there anything more enlightening about monads than this idea?

Yes, very much so!

Monadic binding is a way of composing functions where *something else* is happening over and above the application of a function to an input. What the *something else* is depends on the monad under consideration.

- The `Maybe` monad is function composition with the possibility that one of the functions in the chain might fail, in which case the failure is automatically propagated to the end of the chain. The expression `return x >>= f >>= g` applies `f` to the value `x`. If the result is `Nothing` (i.e. failure) then the entire expression returns `Nothing`, with no other work taking place. Otherwise, `g` is applied to `f x` and its result is returned.
- The `Either e` monad, where `e` is some type, is function composition with the possibility of failure with an error of type `e`. This is conceptually similar to the `Maybe` monad, but we get some more information about how and where the failure occured.
- The `List` monad is function composition with the possibility of returning multiple values. If `f` and `g` are functions that return a list of outputs, then `return x >>= f >>= g` applies `f` to `x`, and then applies `g` to every output of `f`, collecting all of the outputs of these applications together into one big list.

Other monads represent function composition in various other contexts. Very briefly:

- The `Writer w` monad is function composition with a value of type `w` being accumulated on the side. For example, often `w = [String]` (a list of strings) which is useful for logging.
- The `Reader r` monad is function composition where each of the functions is also allowed to depend on a value of type `r`. This is useful when building evaluators for domain-specific languages, when `r` might be a map from variable names to values in the language - this allows simple implementation of lexical closures, for example.
- The `State s` monad is a bit like a combination of reader and writer. It is function composition where each function is allowed to depend on, and modify, a value of type `s`.

Answer (score 6):

The composition point of view is in fact quite enlightening in itself.

Monads can be seen as some of "funky composition" between functions of the form `a -> Mb`. You can compose `f : a -> M b` and `g: b -> M c` into something `a -> M c`, via the monad operations (just bind the return value of `f` into `g`).

This turns arrows of the form `a -> M b` as arrows of a category, termed the *Kleisli category* of `M`.

If `M` were not a monad but just a functor, you would be only able to compose `fmap g` and `f` into something `(fmap g) . f :: a -> M (M c)`. Monads have `join :: M (M a) -> M a` that I let you define as an (easy and useful) exercise using only monad operations (for mathematicians, `join` is usually part of the definition of a monad). Then `join . (fmap g) . f` provides the composition for the Kleisli category.

All the funk of monadic composition can thus be seen to happen inside `join`, `join` represents the *composition of side effects*: for `IO` it sequences the effects, for `List` it concatenates lists, for `Maybe` it "stops a computation" when a result is `Nothing`, for `Writer` it sequences the writes, for `State` it sequences operations on the state, etc. It can be seen as an "overloadable semicolon" if you know C-like languages. It is very instructive to think about monads this way.

Of course, Dan Piponi explains this much better than I do, and here is some post of his that you may find enlightening: http://blog.sigfpe.com/2006/06/monads-kleisli-arrows-comonads-and.html

Comment: The type signature of join is `Monad m => m (m a) -> m a`, that's why you couldn't find it.

Comment: Just one thing, if you do not mind: in category theory join is a natural transformation `M ∘ M → M`. Instead of using functor composition, Haskell uses nested type constructor application - `M (M a)`, which is a bit different from `M M a`. In the latter, I think you cannot even give `M` proper kind.

Comment: @Vitus: Could you expand ? It seems to me that `(M . M) a` is by definition `M (M a)`, and that a natural transformation `M . M -> M` is thus just a natural function `M (M a) -> M a` (I rule out `undefined` and friends here). Of course, my notation was sloppy (it is fixed now), if this is what you meant.